# Is it possible to upload to S3 via URL somehow? (Meteor.js)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, meteor

I know that Amazon doesn't provide a pull service for S3, but is it possible to read an image on the server side and then upload it to S3?

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution. I'm using knox node.js package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the [aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.org/package/aws-sdk) Node package. It's pretty well documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/frames.html). For uploading images you use the [`putObject`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property) method.

Example:

```
S3.putObject({
  Bucket: bucketName,
  ACL: 'private',
  Key: fileName,
  ContentType: fileMimeType,
  Body: new Buffer(fileContents, 'binary'),
}, function(err, data) {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it myself but the most advanced file upload solution for Meteor looks to be [collectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS). It has client/server side components, template helpers and uses collections and security in a similar fashion as you normally use them with Meteor.

They have several storage adapters, where one of them can be used to store files in S3: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-s3